# GPA Calculator, how to make letter inputs into numbers

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, letters

I am trying to make a simple GPA calculator. There are 4 forms and I'm trying to make it so a user enters 4 letters (A,B,C,D, or F) and have each of those numbers represent a value (A = 4.0, B=3.0 ect.) And basically just get the average of them all. Right now I just made it so it so it works if the user enters numbers, but now I want to change it so the user enters the letter grades and get the same gpa number. I have no idea how to do this. Please help thank you.

(This is my html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>GPA Calculator</title>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="project6.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="project6.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Enter Your Grades Below</h1>
            <form name="form" id="form">
                <br>
                <input type="text" class="textForm1" name="textForm1"></input><br>
                <input type="text" class="textForm1" name="textForm2"></input><br>
                <input type="text" class="textForm1" name="textForm3"></input><br>
                <input type="text" class="textForm1" name="textForm4"></input><br>
                <button type="button" onClick="getGrade()">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <div id="div">
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

(This is my javascript)

```
var getGrade = function() {
    var inputOne = document.form.textForm1.value;
    var inputTwo = document.form.textForm2.value;
    var inputThree = document.form.textForm3.value;
    var inputFour = document.form.textForm4.value;
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = (Number(inputOne) + Number(inputTwo) + Number(inputThree) + Number(inputFour))/4;
}
```

Comment: How about creating a function with a switch/case inside, which maps each letter to a numerical value? Have you heard of a switch statement before?

Comment: I have heard of them just not familiar with using them as I'm still a beginner. I will look into them more thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read all the answers and all gave me different ideas of what to do, but in the end, I followed mostly what Mike C. did, but not exactly the same way. Here's what I ended up with that worked perfectly.

```
var gradeValues = {
    "A": 4.0,
    "B": 3.0,
    "C": 2.0,
    "D": 1.0,
    "F": 0
};
var getGrade = function() {
    input1 = document.form.input1.value;
    input2 = document.form.input2.value;
    input3 = document.form.input3.value;
    input4 = document.form.input4.value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ((gradeValues[input1] + gradeValues[input2] + gradeValues[input3] + gradeValues[input4]) / 4) + " is your GPA";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is you want to create a mapping between letters and numbers.

The simplest possible way to do this would be a series of `if` statements.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var inputValue = input.value;
  if (inputValue === 'A') {
    inputValue = 4.0;
  } else if (inputValue === 'B') {
    inputValue = 3.0;
  } else if (inputValue === 'C') {
    inputValue = 2.0;
  } else if (inputValue === 'D') {
    inputValue = 1.0;
  } else {
    inputValue = 0.0;
  }
  console.log(inputValue);
});
```

```html
1: <input type="text" />
```

but this gets very tedious, especially if you have multiple inputs. Another option would be to move this functionality into a function then use that function multiple times.

```js
function letterToNumber(letter) {
  if (letter === 'A') {
    return 4.0;
  } else if (letter === 'B') {
    return 3.0;
  } else if (letter === 'C') {
    return 2.0;
  } else if (letter === 'D') {
    return 1.0;
  } else {
    return 0.0;
  }
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  var input2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
  var input3 = document.getElementById('input3').value;
  var input4 = document.getElementById('input4').value;
  
  input1 = letterToNumber(input1);
  input2 = letterToNumber(input2);
  input3 = letterToNumber(input3);
  input4 = letterToNumber(input4);
  console.log(input1, input2, input3, input4);
});
```

```html
1: <input id="input1" type="text" /><br />
2: <input id="input2" type="text" /><br />
3: <input id="input3" type="text" /><br />
4: <input id="input4" type="text" /><br />
<button>Calculate</button>
```

This works fine. You could simplify it even further by creating an object where the keys match the letter and the value matches the actual number value.

```js
var letterToNumber = {
  A: 4.0,
  B: 3.0,
  C: 2.0,
  D: 1.0
};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  var input2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
  var input3 = document.getElementById('input3').value;
  var input4 = document.getElementById('input4').value;
  
  input1 = letterToNumber[input1];
  input2 = letterToNumber[input2];
  input3 = letterToNumber[input3];
  input4 = letterToNumber[input4];
  console.log(input1, input2, input3, input4);
});
```

```html
1: <input id="input1" type="text" /><br />
2: <input id="input2" type="text" /><br />
3: <input id="input3" type="text" /><br />
4: <input id="input4" type="text" /><br />
<button>Calculate</button>
```

No matter what approach you take, remember the basic principle: if I get some value `X` I want to get some value `Y`. These are just examples of how to map that idea.

Comment: I took part of what you wrote on your last code and implemented it into mine and now it works great!

Answer (score 0):

I would create another Javascript function that takes the input and calculates it, and then you can output from that function.

Inside the function, you can change the letters to numbers.

**JavaScript**

```
const calculateGrade = () => {
  const grades = [inputOne, inputTwo, inputThree, inputFour]
  let sum = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    switch (grades[i]) {
      case "A":
        sum += 4.0
      case "B":
        sum += 3.0
      case "C":
        sum += 2.0
      case "D":
        sum += 1.0
    }
  }
  return (sum / 4)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also a JavaScript Map that will handle all the association for you.

[MDN JavaScript Reference: Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```
var vals = new Map();
vals.set("A", 4.0);
vals.set("B", 3.0);
vals.set("C", 2.0);
vals.set("D", 1.0);
vals.set("F", 0.0);
```

And to retrieve:

```
var grade = document.getElementById("myGrade");
var gradeVal = vals.get(grade);
```

Of course you would do the retrieval in a loop, getting the values for all the grades entered by a user and calculating the average. This is just a simple example of using a Map.

Comment: If you have to support old browser versions you can go with the old fashion JavaScript object.